# Canvas particles interactive image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I know its not an acutal problem but I found this demo http://cssdeck.com/labs/interactive-particle-logo

Can someone explain how draw png images on canvas with other objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that example they are using a library called particle slider which takes an image and draws it in particles.

See http://particleslider.com/ for more details.

The exact method you want is here http://particleslider.com/documentation/api#ParticleSlider.getPixelFromImageData

Going into how to write the library from scratch is probably a bit to advanced for a stackoverflow question :)